# Making a Pipe with Regex on Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, angular

I've already asked the similar question here: stackoverflow.com/questions/42674096/how-to-make-a-pipe-with-regex-in-angular2/

Now, I did try the following from the given answer:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name:'regMatch'})
export class RegMatch implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, arg?: any): any {
        let targetMatched = $('div.poll').text();
       // console.log(targetMatched );
        let reg = new RegExp(/\((.+?)\)/);
        let result: any;
        do {
            let matched:any = result;
            console.log(matched);
        }
        while((result = reg.exec(target)) !== null)
    }
}
```

What happens is, when I put this pipe `| regMatch` the loop crashes the browser.

How can I solve this? How can I match the `(a) (b) (c)` or similar and then let's say `BOLD` the `$('div.poll').text();`

Comment: `let reg = /\((.+?)\)/;`

Comment: `let matched:any = res;` <-- Maybe you wanted `= result;`? I don't see any `res` other than that, hence res is `undefined`. I don't see any `target` aswell, but rather a `targetMatched`

Comment: `let reg = /\(([^)]+)\)/g;` - use `/g` to match multiple occurrences and make the RegExp advance its index.

Comment: Guys, the error is in the loop alone. It craches the browser..

Comment: And you don't need to go for while loop.. `let matched:any = str.match(/[^()]*(?=\))/g)`, hope all the brackets are properly closed and it's of depth 1.

Comment: Please write the full answer, with the logic. Let's say 'turn the matched to bold'..

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you need to match or turn bold. This turn the matched to bold' code request makes your question off-topic.

Comment: I need to match the inputted text. If it has (a) (b), then bold the entire text.

Comment: If you use `let reg = /\([^)]+\)/g;`, will it be matching what you need?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking you to put it as an answer so I can give credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a loop with a regex that does not contain a `/g` (global modifier). That means, that each time your regex finds a match, the `lastIndex` property will not change, and during the next iteration, the same match will be found, and so on and so forth, causing an infinite loop.

See [`String#exec` documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

> `lastIndex`       The index at which to start the next match. When "g" is absent, this will remain as 0.

Use

```
let reg = /\([^)]+\)/g;
```

It will match *all* occurrences of `(`, then 1+ chars other than `)` and then a `)`.

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thanks!