# cannot read property of undefined angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular7

I am getting many errors at the dev tools console when adding a service into my component but the code still working but I want to get rid of from these errors

This's the service:

```
 getPagesData(pageSlug: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this._http.get<any[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}wp/v2/pages/?slug=${pageSlug}`);
  }
```

This is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-membership',
  templateUrl: './membership.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./membership.page.scss'],
})
export class MembershipPage implements OnInit {


  public pageContent: any = {};
  public content: string;

  constructor(
    private _data: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._data.getPagesData('memberships')
      .subscribe(
        page => this.pageContent = page[0]
      )
  }

  getContent(): string {
    return this.pageContent.content.rendered.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, "");
  }

}
```

What cause the errors is the **getContent()** method! it says that is the **.rendered** is an undefined property but it doses defined on the API!

I have searched on that problem and most of the solutions I found it's about using the symbol **?** at HTML template but I can't use that in the component itself.

Comment: Can you please create a minimum reproduction on stackblitz ?

Comment: When you want to change some content or modify it use pipes.See the folowing discussion on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693244/making-a-pipe-with-regex-on-angular2 Official angular guide:https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: You need to share where exactly you are calling `getContent()` and attempting to use `pageContent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you cannot use `?` Elvis (Safe navigation) operator in the component itself because it is designed for view part only.

But you can add some check in the component too to avoid such errors like -

```
getContent(): string {
    const dataToReturn = this.pageContent && this.pageContent.content && this.pageContent.content.rendered.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, "");
    return dataToReturn
  }
```

> .rendered is an undefined property

Also, This error may produce you have defined `pageContent = {}` so on `{}` neither `content` nor `rendered` exist , may be that is also the reason to exist such errors.

Angular recommend to strongly typecast your data before use.

Answer (score 4):

If you are calling `getContent()` in the HTML/template, you can most likely avoid this error by either:

Making `pageContent` initially `null` and using `*ngIf` to only display the content once it has asynchronously resolved:

**Component:**

```
public pageContent: any = null;
```

**Template:**

```
<div *ngIf="pageContent">{{getContent()}}</div>
```

Or you could instead RxJS operators such as `map()` and the `async` pipe:

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-membership',
  templateUrl: './membership.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./membership.page.scss'],
})
export class MembershipPage implements OnInit {
  public pageContent: Observable<string>;
  public content: string;

  constructor(private _data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pageContent = this._data.getPagesData('memberships')
      .pipe(
        map(page => page[0].content.rendered.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, ""))
      );
  }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<div>{{pageContent | async}}</div>
```

That being said, you should probably have additional checks to ensure each sub-property is available prior to accessing it, but usually this type of error is because you are attempting to access the contents before they have resolved.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: adding `*ngIf` to the parent or same element works the best in these cases.